# Split .png into multi-page pdf with imagemagick based on whitespace

Tags: pdf, conversion, imagemagick, png, whitespace

Currently I have a hand written image darkened with

```
convert -level 50x100%
```

It contains chunks of text separated by whitespace.
Simply printing the image would split handwriting in half.

Is there a way to split a png file into a multi-page pdf properly?

Answer (score 0):

Fred's "multicrop" imagemagick-based script might work for you or at least put you in the right direction.

http://www.fmwconcepts.com/imagemagick/multicrop/index.php